# UPDATE column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table my.File_List

```
|id | name | position_name | format   |
|1  |ONE   |  X            | A_B_C_D_1|
|2  |TWO   |  Y            | A_N_M_E_2|
|3  |TWO   |  A            | X_Y_9_O_3|
```

i need a query to replace format data for every row like A_(position_name)_B_C_D

eg. for id=1

i want format column data to be like A_X_B_C_D
where X is position_name. 
please suggest a update query..

Comment: [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form): "A relation is in first normal form if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic values". Your `format` column seems to have some form of sub-structure to it. This tends to lead to more and more complex queries as new requirements are discovered.

Answer (score 2):

More generic solution `without hard coding position of '_'`

```
select substring(format, 1, charindex('_',format)) + position_name + 
       substring(format, charindex('_',format),LEN(format))
--Results for first row
'A_X_B_C_D_1'

select substring(format, 1, charindex('_',format)) + position_name + '_B_C_D'
--Results for first row
'A_X_B_C_D'
```

Update query;

```
Update File_List
Set format = substring(format, 1, charindex('_',format)) + position_name + 
             substring(format, charindex('_',format),LEN(format))
```

Answer (score 1):

For `A_B_C_D` to `A_X_B_C_D`:

```
UPDATE File_List
SET format = SUBSTRING(format, 1, 2) + position_name +
             '_' + SUBSTRING(format, 3, LEN(format))
```

For `A_B_C_D` to `A_X_C_D`:

```
UPDATE File_List
SET format = SUBSTRING(format, 1, 2) + position_name +
             SUBSTRING(format, 4, LEN(format))
```

**EDIT:** Saying `LEN(format)-4` instead of `LEN(format)` in the first case will discard the last 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you desired output

```
UPDATE  my.File_List 
SET format = SUBSTRING(format  ,1,2) + position_name + '_' + SUBSTRING(format ,3,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

can i assume that is always in the same position?

If so, something like this works:

```
UPDATE File_List SET format = LEFT(format,2) + position_name + '_' + SUBSTRING(format, 3, LEN(format)-4)
```

This way, discards the last 2 characters, it inserts the position_name always in index 2, and doesn't care about format's size.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  STUFF(Format, 3, 0, position_name+'_')
FROM 
  TableName
```

Update using

```
UPDATE 
  TableName 
SET Format=STUFF(Format, 3, 0, position_name+'_')
```